# Encountered an error during MCP 1.8.8 decompilation

Tags: java, java-8, minecraft, decompiling

I got this error while trying to decompile MCP version 1.8.8

my source version is 1.6
my target version is 1.6

```
 == MCP 9.18 (data: 9.18, client: 1.8.8, server: 1.8.8) ==

 ...

 == Decompiling client using fernflower ==

 ...

 > Applying patches
 'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1

 == ERRORS FOUND ==

 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\util\Cartesian.jav#'
 ==================

 ...

 == ERRORS FOUND in JAVA CODE ==

 error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
 error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
 ==================
```

thanks!

Comment: Formatted the error output, changed the title, corrected tags

Comment: Change the target version to 1.8 and run fernflower on java 8 not java 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 1.6 is not Supported for MCP 918 (1.8.8), Try installing Java 8 from this link:https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot